# web2py form with DB check

Tags: forms, validation, web2py

I'm using web2py forms, but I need to set up a limit for 20 users registration. How can I do it?

PS: Edit to make easy to understand
Thanks in advance.
Best regards!

Comment: I wouldn't say this question is off-topic (it is asking how to code something in a web framework), nor is it seeking debugging help (the OP has not tried some code that has failed). On the other hand, it is a bit unclear, but not so unclear that someone familiar with web2py couldn't [answer it successfully](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30445806/440323).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wish to limit registration to a maximum of 20 users and you are using the standard `/default/user` function from the scaffolding application:

In the `default.py` controller:

```
def user():
    if request.args(0) == 'register' and db.auth_user.count() >= 20:
        form = None
    else:
        form = auth()
    return dict(form=form)
```

In the `default/user.html` view:

```
{{if form is None:}}
<p>Sorry, no more registrations allowed.</p>
{{else:}}
{{=form}}
{{pass}}
```